# Winforms binding questions involving structs

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, collections, struct

Hi coders I have yet another question involving data binding in winforms. I set up a test applications where I have a bindinglist composed of structs called CustomerInfo. I have bound a listbox control to this list and spun a thread to add CustomerInfo items to the bindinglist.

```
namespace dataBindingSample {

public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public BindingList<CustomerInfo> stringList = new BindingList<CustomerInfo>();
    public Thread testThread;

    public Form1() {

        InitializeComponent();

        stringList.AllowNew = true;
        stringList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        listBox1.DataSource = stringList;

        testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hh_net_retask_request_func));
        testThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;

    }

    private void hh_net_retask_request_func() {

        int counter = 1;
        while (true) {


            CustomerInfo cust = new CustomerInfo();
            cust.Name = "Customer "+ counter.ToString();

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

                stringList.Add(cust);

            });

            counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        testThread.Start();
    }

}

public struct CustomerInfo {

    public string Name {

        set {

            name = value;
        }

        get {
            return name;
        }

    }

    private string name;
  }
}
```

What I see in the list box is the name of the struct `dataBindingSample.CustomerInfo` as opposed to the property of the struct. I was under the impression that non complex binding took the first available property.

Please educate me as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to either add an override of `ToString()` to your CustomerInfo class that returns what you'd like displyed in your list box, or set `listBox1.DisplayMemer = "Name"` before setting the `DataSource`.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much, I have accepted this as the answer. One more thing, do you have any good winform data binding books suggestions? I have found a few from 2006 but not as recent as I like.

Comment: @DoubleDunk - no problem, glad to be of assistance.  I've no recommendations on books, I'm afraid - you should be able to find some suggestions either here, or on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There won't be any books past then really, Wpf is the preferred choice for new development.  That should be ok though, WinForms databinding hasn't really changed much, and I suspect its not going to anytime soon.